# Do killstreaks continue across rounds?

Tags: call-of-duty-ww2

In multi-round games like Domination or Capture the Flag, do killstreak (not scorestreak) counts accumulate across both rounds? If I get a Bloodthirsty medal and a couple more kills without dying, then halftime comes and everybody respawns/teams switch sides, will a few more kills get me a Merciless medal, or will I need to get an entire 10-kill streak in the second round?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes they will.** [Here](http://youtu.be/t_HP1PzTsLY) is a quick video I found showing a player getting a kill right before halftime, then 4 kills at the start of next round, and getting the Bloodthirsty medal.